# How to remove spacing between text in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code:

```css
.underline {
  --line: #646B8C;
  --color: #2B3044;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--color);
  position: relative;
  width: 140px;
  margin: 16px 0;
}

.underline span {
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, var(--line) 0%, var(--line) 100%);
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: var(--background-size, 100%) 1px;
  transition: background-size 0.2s linear var(--background-delay, 0.15s);
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.underline spanS {
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, var(--line) 0%, var(--line) 100%);
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: var(--background-size, 100%) 1px;
  transition: background-size 0.2s linear var(--background-delay, 0.15s);
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 19px;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.underline svg {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: none;
  width: auto;
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  fill: none;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

.underline:hover {
  --background-size: 0%;
  --background-delay: 0s;
  --stroke-dashoffset: 26;
  --stroke-duration: .3s;
  --stroke-easing: cubic-bezier(.3, 1.5, .5, 1);
  --stroke-delay: .195s;
}
```

```html
<p>Through
  <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.datacamp.com/" class="underline">
    <spanS>DataCamp</spanS>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 13 20">
                      <polyline points="0.5 19.5 3 19.5 12.5 10 3 0.5" />
                    </svg>
  </a>, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

How would I remove the space between the comma and `DataCamp`? How would I remove this space:

[image]

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this? I tried removing the `width` property, but it still did not work. What css property is causing this issue?

Comment: it's the SVG taking a lot of spaces

Answer (score 0):

You can place all of your `a` tags code and the following text on one line without any returns in the code editor. This will remove the unwanted [white space](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#white-space-processing) in between the a tag and the comma.

```
  <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.datacamp.com/" class="underline"><span>DataCamp</span><svg viewBox="0 0 13 20"><polyline points="0.5 19.5 3 19.5 12.5 10 3 0.5" /></svg></a>, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

```css
.underline {
  --line: #646B8C;
  --color: #2B3044;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--color);
  position: relative;
  width: 140px;
  margin: 16px 0;
}

.underline span {
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, var(--line) 0%, var(--line) 100%);
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: var(--background-size, 100%) 1px;
  transition: background-size 0.2s linear var(--background-delay, 0.15s);
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.underline spanS {
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, var(--line) 0%, var(--line) 100%);
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: var(--background-size, 100%) 1px;
  transition: background-size 0.2s linear var(--background-delay, 0.15s);
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 19px;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.underline svg {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline;
  width: auto;
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  fill: none;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

.underline:hover {
  --background-size: 0%;
  --background-delay: 0s;
  --stroke-dashoffset: 26;
  --stroke-duration: .3s;
  --stroke-easing: cubic-bezier(.3, 1.5, .5, 1);
  --stroke-delay: .195s;
}
```

```html
<p>Through
  <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.datacamp.com/" class="underline"><spanS>DataCamp</spanS><svg viewBox="0 0 13 20"><polyline points="0.5 19.5 3 19.5 12.5 10 3 0.5" /></svg></a>, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `svg` element between `DataCamp` and coma, it may not render but keep a space. Try to remove it or change `display: inline` to `display: none` in `.underline svg` rule. Also, there is no `spanS` tag in HTML, it should be just `span`.

Comment: I did what you said, but still get the output as whats in the code above (I edited the code above with the changes)

Comment: there is still some space

Answer (score 0):

Add only `margin-right: -5px;` to your `.underline spanS` class.

Answer (score 0):

The space is caused by the `a` tag. You did it like this:

```
<a href="#">foo></a>
bar
```

which yields "foo bar" not "foobar", yes? Same thing is happening with your comma. So if you don't want to move things around you can do that whole thing on one line (not ideal but if you hate it you can rearrange).

Put this all on one line:

```
<a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.datacamp.com/" class="underline">
    <spans>DataCamp</spans>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 13 20">
                      <polyline points="0.5 19.5 3 19.5 12.5 10 3 0.5"></polyline>
                    </svg>
</a>
```

like this:

```
<a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.datacamp.com/" class="underline"><spans>DataCamp</spans><svg viewBox="0 0 13 20"><polyline points="0.5 19.5 3 19.5 12.5 10 3 0.5"></polyline></svg></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The unwanted gap between the end of DataCamp and the comma seems to be caused by whitespace in the HTML.

This snippet removes the newline before the svg tag and the one before the closing a tag.

```css
.underline {
  --line: #646B8C;
  --color: #2B3044;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--color);
  position: relative;
  width: 140px;
  margin: 16px 0;
}

.underline span {
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, var(--line) 0%, var(--line) 100%);
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: var(--background-size, 100%) 1px;
  transition: background-size 0.2s linear var(--background-delay, 0.15s);
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.underline spanS {
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, var(--line) 0%, var(--line) 100%);
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: var(--background-size, 100%) 1px;
  transition: background-size 0.2s linear var(--background-delay, 0.15s);
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 19px;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.underline svg {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: none;
  width: auto;
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  fill: none;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

.underline:hover {
  --background-size: 0%;
  --background-delay: 0s;
  --stroke-dashoffset: 26;
  --stroke-duration: .3s;
  --stroke-easing: cubic-bezier(.3, 1.5, .5, 1);
  --stroke-delay: .195s;
}
```

```html
<p>Through
  <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.datacamp.com/" class="underline">
    <spanS>DataCamp</spanS><svg viewBox="0 0 13 20">
                      <polyline points="0.5 19.5 3 19.5 12.5 10 3 0.5" />
                    </svg></a>, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```